# How to load a custom stylesheet for 2 useragents?

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have two user agent strings:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5
```

The first targets iOS5 and the second targets iOS4.

Is it possible to load a custom stylesheet for the first user agent string, then a different one for the later user agent string?

Comment: Just check the User-Agent in PHP and alter the html to include the right css file.

Comment: Just be aware that user agent detection is not 100% reliable so you should have a failover in place.

Comment: Why is not reliable? What are alternatives for the iPad to differentiate between browsers?

Comment: It's not reliable in the sense that the user agent can be set and overridden by any script.

Answer (score 1):

this tutorial should be helpful, it explains it in details : 
http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad

Comment: I'd probably go along with javascript, but I don't know entirely what it would look like... the link doesn't use the kind of user agent string I was using, and I can't find anything on google that does either. They use `userAgent.match(/iPad/i)` which targets the iPad, but I need to target a certain browser agent for a certain version of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

if you uses **php**, just check `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` for value you need and place `<link href="yourstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` in **head** tag